# How to get the html of CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am diving in the deep end of this magic world of HTML. I have the CKEditor woring and myFunction produces the alert. I need to get the HTML of the text in the editor.

I got this from another post:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.on( 'instanceReady', function( instanceReadyEventObj )
{
var editorInstanceData = CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.getData();
alert( editorInstanceData );
});
```

I could not comment or reply to the post as I don't have enough points so I have to ask a duplicate.
I have the alert working and pasted the code in myFunction but I get the error in the console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{

var htmldata = CKEDITOR.instances.Editor.document.getBody().getHtml();
alert(htmldata);
}
</script>
    <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
    <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
    <script src="http://www.wilsea.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.....
        </textarea>
        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

MrWarby

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.wilsea.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor
        </textarea>

<script>
function myFunction()
{

alert('test');

CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.on( 'instanceReady', function( instanceReadyEventObj )
{
var editorInstanceData = CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.getData();
alert( editorInstanceData );
});


}
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried moving into different place but I still get the same error.

test page is at http://www.wilsea.com/ckeditor/testckeditor.html

MrWarby.

Comment: Can anyone correct my code so it display correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Before your SCRIPT in HEAD add two more lines:

```
<script type="text/javaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

But change path to CkEditor script.